# Action does not find View or its master

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the following action:

```
public class ArticlesController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Article01()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

which returns the view and everything seems to work fine.

Now I try to add ActionName:

```
    [ActionName("bla-bla-article-1")]
    public ActionResult Article01()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Now calling: /Article/Article01 returns

> 'The resource cannot be found.'

Now I try this:

```
[ActionName("bla-bla-article-1")]
public ActionResult Article01()
{
    return View("~/Content/Views/Articles/Article01.cshtml");
}
```

And here I get:

> The view '~/Content/Views/Articles/Article01.cshtml' or its master was
>   not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The
>   following locations were searched:
>   ~/Content/Views/Articles/Articles01.cshtml

Comment: your action will be on the url `/Article/bla-bla-article-1` not `/Article/Article01`

Comment: Your second error says the view doesn't exist. If your controller is called `Article` your looking in a Article**s** (plural) folder which is likely your problem

Comment: Basically `return View("~/Content/Views/Article/Article01.cshtml");` should fix it

Answer (score 1):

You have to realize that by default, the method name is also the action name. But, once you're overriding that convention by using the `[ActionName]` attribute, the Url through which you access the action is subject to change as well.

In your case that would probably be:

> /Articles/bla-bla-article-1

And, when you're using `return View()` without specifying the view name, it's being determined automatically from the current route parameters, and after your attribute is applied, the value would be `bla-bla-article-1`.

That's why you have to specify it explicitly:

```
return View("Article01");
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.view(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Controller.View)